# Automation testing using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium RC command `selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000")` is not working in WebDriver.
Is there any alternate command for this in WebDriver?

Comment: How do you define "not working"? Is it not waiting? Does it throw an error? Does the page finish loading but webdriver keeps on waiting?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of waits you can use in Selenium; implicit and explicit.

Below examples are written in Java:

1) Explicit Wait:

```
new WebDriverWait(super.getDriver(), 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(site_logo));
```

Above code will wait 10 seconds for site logo element to be clickable, if not it will throw an exception. ExpectedConditions class has bunch of other methods you can use. You can check whether an element is present or not etc...

2) Implicit Wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

There is also Thread.sleep(Time in milliseconds); method, but I don't recommend you to use this one.

For more information: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriveWait to solve it:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

For waiting to an element, use wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated) :

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
    driver.get("example.html");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementLocation)));       
    driver.close();
}
```